# PHP File successfully recieved Form Data, not sent to $_POST[]

Tags: php, post, request, isset

I'm trying to access some data I've sent to this page (pincode.php), by using the $_POST[] array. However, it seems the variable isn't set, even though the network tab shows the data got succesfully sent.

[image: Image of successfull POST request]

The code I use to get the value from the $_POST[] array (in the pincode.php file):

```php
if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
$id_buy = $_POST['buy'];
echo $id_buy;
}
```

The problem is the if-statement doesn't fire, so apperently $_POST['buy'] isn't set.

Does anyone know a possible cause?

UPDATE:
As a test, I've created the file: test.php, with the following content:
[image]

This creates the following result and I still don't get the echo:
[image]

I am getting the same issue here, am I missing something important?

Comment: It could be many things. For example, you might have failed to name any of your form inputs "buy": `<input type="text" name="buy">`

Comment: @S.Imp If he didn't have the name, why would the Network tab show that a parameter was sent with that name?

Comment: Are you submitting a form normally or using AJAX?

Comment: Not the cause, just the documentation about what you can expect to work: [PHP: Variables From External Sources (Docs)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php). Additionally: Whatever *fire* means, lets assume you're looking for the output of `179`. If `179` is not part of the response there are two reasons: It was never output from the script or it was output but the connection already closed / output buffering may have skipped it. Use `error_log` temporarily, scan the SAPI error log if those messages appear. Alternatively use step debugging (if available).

Comment: In case of AJAX compare with https://stackoverflow.com/q/5004233/367456 (the basic principles behind that are the same as outlined in the PHP Docs earlier, just additional examples / references for the browser [a.ka. client] part). Network tab should also allow you to inspect response data next to request data. Verify response headers are as expected as well next to the response data itself.

Comment: I am using AJAX, yes. I will try out your suggestions tommorow! Thank you for responding

Comment: @Barmar i see no mention of the word 'buy' on that image of the 'network tab'.

Comment: @S.Imp You don't see `buy: 179` on the last line?

Comment: I've performed another test, maybe this will clear up the situation a bit more. I've put the result in my original post. Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: @barmar the post has since changed, but I saw no appearance of the word 'buy' on the image at all.